# Manage string arguments passed to function without enum

Tags: c#, string, enums, arguments, wrapper

I'm using a WebRequest to make calls to an API. I want to make a wrapper for the call that specifies the variable routing to use. At the moment, all I can come up with is an enum and then a switch statement.

```
public void WebRequestWrapper(MyEnum arg)
{
    string argument = string.Empty;
    switch(arg)
    {
        case MyEnum.MySpecifiedArgument:
            argument = "MySpecifiedArgument";
            break;
        // etc etc...
    }
    var request = new WebRequest.Create(myUrl + argument);
    // etc, etc...
}
```

My question is, is there a way around using an enum so that I don't have to use a switch statement? So I could do:

```
public void WebRequestWrapper(MyArgCollection arg)
{
    var request = new WebRequest.Create(myUrl + arg);
    // etc, etc...
}
```

where MyArgCollection would be some custom class/struct/something-like-an-enum and 'arg' would represent a string? I know I could use reflection and enum helper classes, but I've read that that isn't particularly fast.

With an enum, you could have:

```
enum MyEnum {
stuff = 3,
fred = 5,
plant = 125
}
```

Whereas what I'd like would be:

```
enum MyEnum {
stuff = "Things in my room",
fred = "A guy down the street",
plant = "No longer alive"
}
```

Obviously, the latter isn't legal. But is there some way of using a struct, class, whatever that could make this work?
Please let me know if this doesn't make sense. Thanks!

Comment: How your second sample related to first one? In first sample you are passing single argument of `MyEnum` type. In second sample you are passing `MyArgCollection` of unknown type. Also there should be `MyEnum.MySpecifiedArgument` instead of `enum.MySpecifiedArgument` (actually I have doubts whether you can use `enum` keyword as variable name)

Comment: Well, what I was hoping for was an enum-like collection with members that would return a string, not an integer. So in an enum if you say `MyEnum.MyType`, you may get 0 normally, in this instance you would get something like "This is my type". Does that make sense??

Comment: Question still unclear. I don't understand what you pass as `MyArgCollection` and how want to use it. And what first sample of code is about?

Comment: I just edited it. I'm sorry this isn't making much sense... :(

Comment: You cannot have strings in enum

Comment: I know that. I'm looking for an alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE AFTER QUESTION CHANGE:
So, you want to attach a custom string to each Enum value. You can use attributes for that:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Things in my room")]
    stuff,
    [Description("A guy down the street")]
    fred,
    ...
}
```

You'll need to create the `DescriptionAttribute` class, of course.

Then you can add an extension method:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum e);
```

This method will see if the enum's value has a `DescriptionAttribute`, and if so - return its content. If not, it should probably return `e.ToString()`.

ANSWER TO OLD QUESTION:
You can use `arg.ToString()` to get its string representation.